# Strange data when fetching associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my app I have 1:n relationship between two models.

```
class BuildsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user_application = UserApplication.find(params[:user_application_id])
    @build = @user_application.builds.create(params[:build].permit(:version, :description))
    redirect_to user_application_path(@user_application)
  end
end


class UserApplicationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user_applications = UserApplication.all
  end

  def new
    @user_application = UserApplication.new
  end

  def create
    @user_application = UserApplication.new(user_application_params)
    if @user_application.save
      redirect_to @user_application
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user_application = UserApplication.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user_application = UserApplication.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user_application = UserApplication.find(params[:id])

    if @user_application.update(params[:user_application].permit(:name))
      redirect_to @user_application
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user_application = UserApplication.find(params[:id])
    @user_application.destroy

    redirect_to user_applications_path
  end

  private
  def user_application_params
    params.require(:user_application).permit(:name)
  end
end

<p>
  <strong>Name: </strong>
  <%= @user_application.name %>
</p>

<h2>Add a build</h2>

<%= form_for([@user_application, @user_application.builds.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :version %>
      <%= f.text_field :version %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Builds</h2>
<%= @user_application.builds.each do |build| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Version:</strong>
      <%= build.version%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Description:</strong>
      <%= build.description %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

The structure is very similar to [Blog app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). But on the show page which I posted above, I see a strange data rendered. It looks like this:

```
Version:

Description:

[#<Build id: 1, description: "Initial", version: "1.0", user_application_id: 2, created_at: "2014-03-13 18:52:47", updated_at: "2014-03-13 18:52:47">, #<Build id: nil, description: nil, version: nil, user_application_id: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

What is that?

**UPD**

Now my problem is that though there are no records in DB for dependant objects, template for Build model is rendered at least one time.

If I log the value of @user_application.builds.emtpy? it yields "false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the = `<%=` on the `each`. Using this way, you are outputing the builds array.
To output only what is inside block, use `<% @user_application.builds.each do |build| %>`

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem. But still, I have output from this cycle even if the array is builds array is empty. This time I have only content of <strong> tags. But if I log the builds.count it's 0. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That's because `@user_application.builds.build` on `form_for`. This is creating a `Build` instance in `user_application.builds` array. As this is not persisted, `count` is returning 0.  In `form_for`you don't need build to be associated to user_application, so using `<%= form_for([@user_application, Build.new]) do |f| %>` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<%= @user_application.builds.each do |build| %>`

For `<% @user_application.builds.each do |build| %>`

The weird data you see is just how ruby prints an array of hashes

Comment: Yes, that's it. Can you please take a look at my comment to @Bulezim answer?

Comment: The array should be empty, but still there's one iteration of a loop.